# Add CSS Class to Div by checking the Span text

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

How do you add css class to the first div(see below) if the span inside that div is "Yes". This div does not have an id. How do you search for this div and modify.

```html
<div class="dx-button dx-button-normal dx-widget dx-button-has-icon dx-button-has-text" role="button" aria-label="Yes" tabindex="0">
  <div class="dx-button-content">
    <span class="dx-button-text">Yes</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post some code. Happy to help

Comment: @PraveenGopal code was posted - just not formatted properly so it got hidden, I have edited for OP (Always good to check the post for new users as this often happens)

Comment: [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) should set you on the right path. Good luck!

Comment: You have class name for span so use "document.getElementsByClassName"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this?

```
var dxBtnText = document.querySelector('.dx-button-text').textContent;

if (dxBtnText == 'Yes') {
    document.querySelector('.dx-button').classList.add('new-class-name');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot apply `DevExtreme css` to the button, I tried with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/17.2.5/css/dx.common.css" />` but it does not load, but the below code in theory should work:

```js
let btnElement = $('.dx-button');
let btnText = $(".dx-button-text").text();

console.log(btnText)

if (btnText == 'Yes') {
  btnElement.addClass("dx-button-yes");
}
```

```css
.dx-button-yes {
  background-color: lightBlue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- dunno how to include DevExtreme in order to have your css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/17.2.5/css/dx.common.css" />

<div class="dx-button dx-button-normal dx-widget dx-button-has-icon dx-button-has-text" role="button" aria-label="Yes" tabindex="0">
  <div class="dx-button-content">
    <span class="dx-button-text">Yes</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dxBtnText = document.querySelectorAll(".dx-button-text");

dxBtnText.forEach(element => {
    if (element.innerText == "Yes") {
         element.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add("your-new-class-name");
    }
});
```